# How to cancel multiple user accounts and keep their content without using built-in admin GUI?

Tags: users, rules, views

How do I cancel/delete multiple user accounts without deleting content created by those users and without using the built-in admin GUI?

Ideally if there was a way via VBO or rules or any related modules that would be awesome.

Comment: why wouldn't you want to use the gui?

Comment: Be careful using VBO to delete users. If you use 'Delete item' on a user based view, it will delete those users and _all_ their content by default ( see https://drupal.org/node/1885294 ).

Comment: use admin gui, not VBO, and just block users, do not delete them, you willl keep all data and users won't  have access.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hannesl/3864416

Answer (score 0):

You can check out some of these things. 
Please test this before using it on your real build.

[Delete All module](https://drupal.org/project/delete_all)

> > This module is used to delete all content and/or users from a site. This is mainly a developer tool, which can come in handy in several
> >     cases, listed below.
>
> The usual way to do this is to go to Administer -> Content then select
>   all the nodes and delete them. This works if you have a handful of
>   nodes only. If you have hundreds or thousands of nodes, then it is not
>   a practical solution.
>
> Another option is to directly delete the nodes from the node table in
>   the database. This does not work properly, since there are also
>   comments, and many tables for add on modules that needs to be cleaned.
>
> This is a test site that the client was using for a period of time,
>   and they must clean it up before starting with real data. You are
>   testing something that creates a lot of nodes (e.g. aggregator), and
>   want to do it over and over again. You created a site in the past and
>   want to replicate it again, but with new content. Note that for nodes,
>   comments and all additions to nodes that contributed modules may have
>   added. For users, any additional module data will also be deleted.

but you can also use Drush and this command `drush delete-all users`